# Error from ISP using JQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using VB.NET in Express 2008. I use a lot of $Ajax code and all is working fine in Development. But I deployed a simple $Ajax snippet to the ISP server and the Ajax did not work. I created a ticket and got this from the Tech: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'd' of null - default.aspx:31

Here is the Ajax:

```
function AJAX_GetVoice(strVoice) { 
var obj = {};
obj.strVoice = strVoice;
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(obj);
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "Voice.asmx/GetVoice",
data: jsonData,
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
global: true, // disable ajaxSend, etc
success: function OnSuccess(response) { 

//Note:here is line 31 below

if (response.d == 'Success') {
alert("Success");
}
}
```

Perhaps the datatype is wrong and it should be HTML and the return instaed of response.d should ben data.

Can anyone help?

Here is the entire web service:

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX,     uncomment the following line.  
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _  
<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _  
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _  
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _  
Public Class Voice  
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService  
<WebMethod()> _  
Public Function GetVoice(ByVal strVoice As String) As String  
Return "Success"  
End Function  
End Class
```

Comment: The error is coming from your asmx code, and you haven't provided that code. So I doubt it.

Comment: This error is not from asmx. The problem is that asmx did not sent any reponse (the response object is null).

Comment: The asmx file points to <%@ WebService Language="VB" CodeBehind="App_Code/Voice.vb" Class="Voice" %>

Comment: service returns: Return "Success"